# A change of plan

Tags: future-tense

Think about plans you've had which changed.

Use these or your own ideas…

• meeting friends

• commuting / traveling

• planning an event

Answer these questions:

1. What were you planning to do?
2. What went wrong?
3. What did you do about it?
4. What happened in the end?

Comment: Why are you asking these questions? What's the problem here? What do you want to know?

Comment: This sounds like a homework exercise, without any clear single question.

Comment: Yes, but I did not know how to form sentences and how to link them together, may I know and learn how to write them? I wrote and I want to know if my writing is correct and my sentences are correct or not
thank you in advance.

Comment: I was going to go to the airport and my flight departs at 8:00 , But I hung in traffic .  I arrived at the airport late and lost my flight . That was okay. And I booked another put me on another flight later at 9:00

Answer (score 0):

Questions like these are personal.  This means the only correct answers are the ones from your life.  After all, your plans are not my plans.

If you try to answer these questions, and then decide your English doesn't sound right, please ask a different question.  In that question, you should ask if your answer is a natural thing to say in English.